# Android How to fix bottom of UI, cut off by AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout

I am using CoordinatorLayout for my activity_main layout, to show a RecyclerView list of CardViews.  All works well except when there are no CardViews...an empty list.  When I add "app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" to my ConstraintLayout that holds the <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView /> the UI extends the height of the empty list and the white border for the layout becomes cut off at the bottom of the UI.

What am I missing here?  Can't I constrain the bottom of the ConstraintLayout to the height of the UI with an empty list that does not need to be extended yet since there are not CardViews yet?  Layout is below.

The empty list with the white border missing at the bottom of the list:

[image]

I want the empty list to show the white border at the bottom of the empty list like this:

[image]

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".MainActivity"  >

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/action_logo"
            android:title="@string/action_logo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_s_logo_48x48"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    android:id="@+id/con_layout"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar_id"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/appbar_id"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/todoListLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"  >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/filterListTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sortListTV"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sortListTV"
            android:text="@string/filter"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/quickListTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:text="@string/quicklist"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:tooltipText="sort quicklist by default"
            tools:targetApi="o" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sortListTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:text="@string/sort"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_sort_white_24dp"
            app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/ic_sort_white_24dp" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvQuickcards"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/quickListTV"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_todo"  />            

        <!-- Added an empty view which will be shown when the EmptyRecyclerView
         is empty -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/quickListTV"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/onboardingViewStub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
                android:layout="@layout/custom_stub2" />

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/taptheplusStub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/onboardingViewStub"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
                android:layout="@layout/custom_stub3" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If you just want the bottom border, why not give the `ConstraintLayout` a `marginBottom`? Also, Why both Relative and Constraint layouts?

Comment: I tried adding a layout_marginBottom="10dp" to the ConstraintLayout.  It did not do anything to fix the problem.  Also, what can I use instead of the RelativeLayout for id="@+id/todoListLayout".

Comment: Then, Give the Parent `CoordinatorLayout` a `paddingBottom`, it will do the job. Other than this, all the constraints in the `ConstraintLayout` tag are useless because the parent is not `ConstraintLayout` so they cause no change. Also, by why both, I meant to say `ContraintLayout` is meant to be flat layout in which you don't have to use another layout to align widgets, so, unless, the `RelativeLayout` is there because of some scrolling behaviour issue, both of the RelativeLayouts redundant.

Comment: Ok, I will try the paddingBottom.  Because I have use of two RelativeLayouts should I remove the ConstraintLayout and replace it with a FrameLayout or a LinearLayout?

Comment: paddingBottom did the trick.  Cheers!

Comment: Instead, remove both the `RelativeLayouts`, you don't actually need them. One `ConstraintLayout` is enough.